# How to install 11.10 with wubi?

Tags: 11.10, wubi

All that is available for wubi installation is Ubuntu 12.04, but I strongly prefer 11.10.  Is there any way that I can use wubi installer for 11.10?

Answer (score 1):

12.04 is recommended because it the latest release, but if you would like Wubi for 11.10, [here is a direct link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/oneiric/wubi.exe) to the appropriate `wubi.exe` file.

*Please note* that Ubuntu 11.10 is only supported until April 2013, at which point you should upgrade if you are still using it for security reasons if nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Wubi for Ubuntu 11.10 is available at http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/wubi.exe.

You can find all previous Ubuntu, Wubi and related files at http://releases.ubuntu.com/.